# Probability distribution of the future stock price

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, finance

I have this exercise to do:

Consider a stock with an initial price of $40, an expected return of 16% per annum and a volatility of 20% per annum. Find the probability distribution of the future stock price in 6 months' time. Determine the 95% confidence of interval.

$S_0=40$

$\mu=0.16$

$\sigma=0.20$

$T=0.5$

Using the lognormal property of stock prices $(\ln{S_T}\approx\varphi\left[\ln{S_0}+\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T,\ \sigma^2T\right]$, I have $\ln{S_T}\approx\varphi\left[3.759,\ 0.02\right]$.

The results of the textbook says "there is a 95% probability that a normally distributed variable has a value within 1.96 standard deviaton of its mean."

Viewing another topic from this forum, I found this possible solution: $P[lnS_T>ln95]=1−P[lnS_T<ln95]=1−P[Z<z=\frac{ln95-3.759}{\sqrt{0.02}}]$ 
If I want to compute $z$, as result I will have $z=5.62$. Thus, $N(5.62)=1$ (is not possible for this exercise).

Supposing a 95% c.i. I can't solve the problem. Is anyone can explain me how can I approach it?

I would be beyond thankful for any help and advice.

Comment: "$\textrm{The results of the textbook says "there is a 95% probability that a normally distributed ...}$" This statement just means that $P(-1.96 \leq Z \leq 1.96)=0.95$, where $Z\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$

Comment: Thank you, now I've understood my mistake

Comment: That makes me happy. You´re welcome.